# Tomcat - enabling two-way SSL

Tags: authentication, ssl, tomcat6, ssl-certificate

I am using Windows XP and running Tomcat 6.
I am trying to enable SSL on Tomcat. First, I tried it with client authentication.

It didn't work - and I configured it to work without client authentication.

I have certificate installed on the tomcat server, and also the CA certificate installed on the browsers (IE & FireFox).

It still doesn't work.

In IE the server doesn't throw any exception except for EOFException.

In FireFox it throws SSLHandeShakeException: Remote host close the connection.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to connect via Browser using https:// on a non-SSL port.

Comment: You haven't provided details of your Connector configuration from server.xml nor are there any details of how you have "installed" your certificate on Tomcat.

Comment: i configured the connector to work on a ssl port.   my connector looks like that                                           "<Connector port="8443" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keyStoreFile ="c:/myCertificate.jks" 
           keyStorePass="c:/myCertificate.jks"
           clientAuth="false" SSLProtocol="TLS"/>"

Comment: Did you really mean `keyStorePass="c:/myCertificate.jks"`?

Comment: What do you mean, Bruno? Where is the difference?

Comment: `keystorePass` is for the keystore password, not its location (check the case as well: small s). You should set `keyPass` instead (or both if you have a different password). Check [the documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSL configuration as provided in the comments is highly suspect - particularly the keyStorePass attribute. I suggest you work from the [Tomcat SSL docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) and proceed in the following order:

- Get https working from a browser with a self-signed certificate
- Then get it working with a proper certificate
- Then try and add client certificate authentication

This does all work. It is tested as part of the Servlet TCK and every Tomcat release passes the TCK.